# Does Action Cable 5 require Redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, actioncable

I use:

```
rails (5.0.2)
actioncable (5.0.2)
puma (3.8.2)
```

I have a Rails 5 Action Cable demo chat and a year ago it didn't work without Redis - and now it does! (after `bundle update`).

In other words, I succedeed to make my demo chat to work in development mode **without Redis**. I set `the config/cable.yml` like this:

```
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: async
```

and start `rails c`. That's it - the chat is working, no problem. So Redis is obviously not needed anymore - unlike a year-ago times?

Also I found a way to make my demo chat to work **with Redis**. To do so I change `the config/cable.yml` like this:

```
redis: &redis
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

production: *redis
development: *redis
test: *redis
```

than add `gem 'redis', '~>3.2'` to my Gemfile (+ `bundle install`), start Redis `redis-server` and then `rails c`.

So my questions are:

1. Does Action Cable 5 require Redis to work? (looks like don't but I'm not sure).
2. If (apparently) Action Cable 5 can work **with or without Redis** - what's the difference?
3. What is `gem 'redis', '~>3.2'`? What is it for?

Generally I have no idea what is now the proper usage of Action Cable 5 in terms of Redis usage (non-usage?). Is there any difference for the development or production mode?

Answer (score 8):

> Does Action Cable 5 require Redis?

No. According to the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#subscription-adapter), it's able to use other adapters.

> Action Cable provides a **subscription adapter interface to process its
>   pubsub internals.** By default, asynchronous, inline, PostgreSQL,
>   evented Redis, and non-evented Redis adapters are included. The
>   default adapter in new Rails applications is the asynchronous (async)
>   adapter.

Questions:

> Does Action Cable 5 require Redis to work? (looks like don't but I'm
>   not sure).

No.

> If (apparently) Action Cable 5 can work with or without Redis - what's the difference?

In case of ActionCable there in no differences, it uses an abstraction `adapter` and does not depend on transport protocol.

> What is `gem 'redis', '~>3.2'`? What is it for?

It's for redis and provides an interface for communication with redis-server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the async adapter in dev, but the docs state that

> The async adapter is intended for development/testing and should not
>   be used in production.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#configuration

I tried it anyway - and at least with my setup (nginx, passenger) - the async adapter just didn't work. I'm guessing thread/process issues

For production, that leaves you the option of Redis or PostgreSql